# How to get LowCodeUnit to recognize my fontawesome CSS file?

Tags: font-awesome

The pages of my site in LowCodeUnit are properly loading all but one of my .css files - specifically 'font-awesome.min.css' which I have referenced as such (and validated on server)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

How do I get my font-awesome icons to load properly?

Answer (score 0):

We've had success replacing the stylesheet reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

with a javascript reference instead:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0b7385f8de.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```